# Change Text every 24 hours in Dart (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of text that I would like to display on the home screen of the app. I want it to change every 24hours.

How's best to complete this?

Comment: Do you want to change local data on phone ?

Comment: Yes, it’d be locally on the phone

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a timer because if you close the app you will lost the timer. I suggest you to save a timestamp in shared preferences and every time you open the app you will check if 24 hours have passed since the timestamp you saved.
If 24 hours have passed, update the timestamp with the new one and you will change the list with another one. I take it for granted that the lists are saved somewhere in the app or via ws

I forgot to mention that you can check if 24 hours have passed or if the day has passed. It depends if you want to change every 24 hours or every change of the day

[Link for shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)